# Oriented area of a closed contour, consisting of line segments (curves)

Tags: element, point, area, curve

There is some code that determines the "orientation" of the path - i.e. clockwise it is drawn or counterclockwise.
I can't understand how the area is calculated for the current segment p1 - p2:

Ar += (p1.y+p2.y)*(p1.x-p2.x)/2

There is an assumption that the coordinates of the curve (segment) are translated into coordinates x and y, and the sum of the integrals is calculated
But since division by 2 (ab / 2) occurs, the areas of the triangles may be summed up.

```
for (int i = 0;i < m_pCoEdges.GetSize();i++) // passing through an array of elements (segments) that make up a closed contourcfgn
{
m_pCoEdges[i]->GetUVCurve()->GetPointAt(0.0,p1); // for the current segment (contour), its first (starting 0.0) point p1 (end point of segment 1.0) is taken and converted to x and y coordinates
    for (double t = Step;t < 1.0 + Step/2;t+=Step)''' //the second point is taken on the same segment (curve) with a step of Step = 0.01
    {
        m_pCoEdges[i]->GetUVCurve()->GetPointAt(t,p2);//the second point p2 of the same segment is taken and converted to coordinates x and y
        Ar += (p1.y+p2.y)*(p1.x-p2.x)/2; //**calculates the area from p1 to p2. I'm trying to figure out how**
        p1 = p2;
    }
}
```

The question arose in connection with the change in the code, the transition to new functions, in which there is no translation of a point on a curve into 2D coordinates, there is a translation into 3D (global coordinates), and, accordingly, the calculation of the oriented area of ​​the contour using x, y, z.
Any help in determining the method used for calculating the oriented area, and counting using the three coordinates of the point p1 b p2